# Is there a exponent operator in C?

Tags: c, operators, exponent

I want to do an exponent calculation in C. I tried `**`, but compiler threw an error.

Is there such operator in C? If not, how to calculate exponent?

Comment: In C/C++ the operator `^`is the arithmetic xor!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't such operator in C. There are functions for this: `pow()`, `powf()`, `powl()` (respectively for `double`, `float` and `long double`) defined in header *math.h*

First parameter is base, second exponent.

Of course, them being defined for floating point types, doesn't mean you cannot use them for integers.

```c
int x = pow(10, 2);
```

The result of `pow()` will be properly cast from `100.0` to `100` and assigned to integer variable `x`

Comment: It is typically not a good idea to use floating point arithmetic when working with integers, and you expect exact results. You really have to know what you are doing. `(int) pow(10, 2)` will probably return `100`, but to make sure it doesn't return `99` you have to read and understand all the relevant parts of the C and  IEEE 754 standards. In this case, it is much simpler, faster and safer to just do `10 * 10`.